# Let ,  ∈ ℤ,  = { ∈ ℤ ∶ |} and  = { ∈ ℤ ∶ |}. Then  ⊆  if and only if |.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Very rough question here, can someone just guide me on how to start it? I am directionless

Comment: What does it mean for a set to be a subset of another?

Comment: Let's get you started with the easier direction.  Assume that $c \vert d$ and assume further that $x \in C$.  Can you prove then that also $x \in D$?  If you can, then you've proved $c \vert d \Rightarrow C \subseteq D$.  Use your definition of what it means for $a \vert b$, both in connection with the assumption that $c \vert d$ and also with the assumption that $x \vert c$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof: let $C = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x | c \}$ and $D = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}: x |d \}$

Suppose $C \subset D$, then as $c|c$ we have that $c \in C \underset{C\subset D}{\implies} c \in D$

Then by definition of $D$ we have that  $c|d$

$ \ \ $

Now suppose $c|d$, let $x \in C$ then $x|c \implies c = xq$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$

And as $c|d \implies d = c.k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Thus $d = c.k = x.q.k = x.\underbrace{(q.k)}_{\in \mathbb{Z}} \implies x|d \implies x \in D \implies C \subset D$

$\blacksquare$